Clique covering number
The clique covering number of a graph $G$ is defined as the minimum number of cliques in $G$ needed to cover the vertex set of $G$. Finding a minimum clique cover in general graphs $G$ is NP-hard, and was one of Karps 21 NP-complete problems.
Is there any resource with clique covering numbers table, besides https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CliqueCoveringNumber.html? With some 'famous' graphs like Peterssen or Clebsch

I am not aware of any such database, but for graphs of girth at least four, like the Petersen or Clebsch graph, the clique covering number is easy to compute. This is because every clique has size one or two, so the clique covering number of such graphs can be found by a maximum matching computation. Namely, the clique covering number is $\nu(G)+(|V(G)|-2\nu(G)) = |V(G)|-\nu(G)$, where $\nu(G)$ is the size of a maximum matching of $G$. For instance, in the case of the Petersen graph, the clique covering number is five, since it has a perfect matching.
A website which lists properties of graphs (like girth) is https://houseofgraphs.org, which could hence be of interest.
